# Не работает Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger2

Подключил в проект Dagger2. Пытаюсь инжектить Retrofit во фрагмент.

**Модуль:**

```
@Module
open class ApiModule {

private val baseUrl = "http://pixabay.com/api/"

@Provides
@Singleton
open fun provideGson(): Gson {
    val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()

    return gsonBuilder.create()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
open fun provideCache(application: Application): Cache {
    val cacheSize = (10 * 1024 * 1024).toLong()
    val httpCacheDirectory = File(application.cacheDir, "http-cache")

    return Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize)
}

@Provides
@Singleton
open fun provideOkhttpClient(cache: Cache): OkHttpClient {
    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    httpClient.cache(cache)
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)
    httpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    return httpClient.build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
open fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
open fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
    return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
}
}
```

**Компонент:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, ApiModule::class])
interface ApiComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder

    fun build(): ApiComponent
}

fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

fun inject(bmwFragment: BmwFragment)
}
```

**Application:**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

private lateinit var apiComponent: ApiComponent

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance = this

    apiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
}

companion object {
    @get:Synchronized
    var instance: MyApplication? = null
        private set
}

fun getApiComponent(): ApiComponent {
    return apiComponent
}
}
```

**Фрагмент:**

```
@Inject
lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit

 override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    (MyApplication.instance as MyApplication)
            .getApiComponent()
            .inject(requireActivity() as MainActivity)
    super.onAttach(context)
}

val client = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
```

Но падает с ошибкой: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property retrofit has not been initialized

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду вы инициализируете `retrofit` переменную в `onAttach()`, а используете при загрузке класса, в поле `client`. В этот момент  `onAttach()` никак не может быть ещё вызван, засим и переменная неинициализрована.

Comment: исправил .inject(requireActivity() as MainActivity) на               .inject(this) заработало